MAUI project does not compile, in certains cases, when referencing objects from a normal .NET Class Library
I just started using MAUI. I want to have 3 projects:

The MAUI app (.NET Core 8)
A Shared class library (.NET Core 8 Class Library)
A Web Api (.NET Core 8)

The Shared class library contains a class "SearchOptions" (TestApp.Shared.Dtos.SearchOptions) which is a simple public class with basic type (int, string, bool, etc.) properties.
The Web API project has a controller with a "Search" method which accepts a parameter of type "SearchOptions".
Now, here lies the problem: When I try to use the "SearchOptions" class in the MAUI project, to send it in a http request, depending on where I use it, I get an error saying the reference cannot be found.
If I use it in /Platforms/Android/MainActivity.cs, for example, the project builds fine.
If I create a "Helpers" folder and a SearchHelper class (/Helpers/SearchHelpser.cs), and use "SearchOptions" in that class, I get an "error CS0234 : The type or namespace name 'Shared' does not exist in the namespace 'TestApp' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"
My question is: How come it builds fine in one place and not in another place? What am I missing? Is there a better way to achieve what I am trying to do?
As I have replied to some of the comments, I already have the project reference in my MAUI app. Without it, it would not work in "Platforms/Android/MainActivity.cs", but it does... so I assume the reference is correct.
I also know how "using" works. Even with a fully qualified class name that includes the full namespace, it does not find it.
Here is the code for each class:
TestApp.Shared.Dtos/Search/SearchOptions.cs:
namespace TestApp.Shared.Dtos.Search
{
    public class SearchOptions
    {
        public string Terms { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public SearchTypes SearchType { get; set; }
    }
}

TestApp.Maui/Helpers/SearchHelper.cs (Does not compile)
using TestApp.Shared.Dtos.Search;

namespace TestApp.Maui.Helpers
{
    internal class SearchHelper
    {
        public void Search()
        {
            var options = new SearchOptions
            {
                SearchType = SearchTypes.ByCar,
                Terms = "Test Terms For Search"
            };
        }
    }
}

TestApp.Maui/Platforms/Android/MainActivity.cs (Compiles)
using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;
using TestApp.Shared.Dtos.Search;

namespace TestApp.Maui
{
    [Activity(Theme = "@style/Maui.SplashTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Density)]
    public class MainActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity
    {
        public void TestMethod()
        {
            var options = new SearchOptions
            {
                SearchType = SearchTypes.ByCar,
                Terms = "Test Terms For Search"
            };
        }
    }
}

Here is the complete error:
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Shared' does not exist in the namespace 'TestApp' (are you missing an assembly reference?)  TestApp.Maui (net8.0-android)   D:\Projects\TestApp\Code\TestApp.Maui\Helpers\SearchHelper.cs   1   N/A
Here is the output:
Build started at 11:51 AM...
1>------ Build started: Project: TestApp.Maui, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>D:\Projects\TestApp\Code\TestApp.Maui\Helpers\SearchHelper.cs(1,17,1,23): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Shared' does not exist in the namespace 'TestApp' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
1>Done building project "TestApp.Maui.csproj" -- FAILED.
1>TestApp.Maui -> D:\Projects\TestApp\Code\TestApp.Maui\bin\Debug\net8.0-android\TestApp.Maui.dll
1>TestApp.Maui -> D:\Projects\TestApp\Code\TestApp.Maui\bin\Debug\net8.0-maccatalyst\maccatalyst-x64\TestApp.Maui.dll
1>TestApp.Maui -> D:\Projects\TestApp\Code\TestApp.Maui\bin\Debug\net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\TestApp.Maui.dll
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Build completed at 11:51 AM and took 02.217 seconds ==========

Here is the project file (to show the reference is there):
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFrameworks>net8.0-android;net8.0-ios;net8.0-maccatalyst</TargetFrameworks>
        <TargetFrameworks Condition="$([MSBuild]::IsOSPlatform('windows'))">$(TargetFrameworks);net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFrameworks>
        <!-- Uncomment to also build the tizen app. You will need to install tizen by following this: https://github.com/Samsung/Tizen.NET -->
        <!-- <TargetFrameworks>$(TargetFrameworks);net8.0-tizen</TargetFrameworks> -->

        <!-- Note for MacCatalyst:
        The default runtime is maccatalyst-x64, except in Release config, in which case the default is maccatalyst-x64;maccatalyst-arm64.
        When specifying both architectures, use the plural <RuntimeIdentifiers> instead of the singular <RuntimeIdentifier>.
        The Mac App Store will NOT accept apps with ONLY maccatalyst-arm64 indicated;
        either BOTH runtimes must be indicated or ONLY macatalyst-x64. -->
        <!-- For example: <RuntimeIdentifiers>maccatalyst-x64;maccatalyst-arm64</RuntimeIdentifiers> -->

        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <RootNamespace>TestApp.Maui</RootNamespace>
        <UseMaui>true</UseMaui>
        <SingleProject>true</SingleProject>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>

        <!-- Display name -->
        <ApplicationTitle>TestApp.Maui</ApplicationTitle>

        <!-- App Identifier -->
        <ApplicationId>com.companyname.TestApp.maui</ApplicationId>

        <!-- Versions -->
        <ApplicationDisplayVersion>1.0</ApplicationDisplayVersion>
        <ApplicationVersion>1</ApplicationVersion>

        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'ios'">11.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'maccatalyst'">13.1</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'android'">21.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'windows'">10.0.17763.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <TargetPlatformMinVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'windows'">10.0.17763.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'tizen'">6.5</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <!-- App Icon -->
        <MauiIcon Include="Resources\AppIcon\appicon.svg" ForegroundFile="Resources\AppIcon\appiconfg.svg" Color="#512BD4" />

        <!-- Splash Screen -->
        <MauiSplashScreen Include="Resources\Splash\splash.svg" Color="#512BD4" BaseSize="128,128" />

        <!-- Images -->
        <MauiImage Include="Resources\Images\*" />
        <MauiImage Update="Resources\Images\dotnet_bot.png" Resize="True" BaseSize="300,185" />

        <!-- Custom Fonts -->
        <MauiFont Include="Resources\Fonts\*" />

        <!-- Raw Assets (also remove the "Resources\Raw" prefix) -->
        <MauiAsset Include="Resources\Raw\**" LogicalName="%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls" Version="$(MauiVersion)" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility" Version="$(MauiVersion)" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="8.0.0" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <ProjectReference Include="..\TestApp.Shared.Dtos\TestApp.Shared.Dtos.csproj" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>


you probably need to add a using statement using TestApp.Shared.Dtos;.   If this doesn't work please edit your question to include the actual relevant code

I already have the proper usings. I'm new to MAUI, but I'm not new to C#. ;) I have tried inside and outside the namespace. While inside the namespace, I can remove part of the using (the common part at the beginning), which I tried with and without. Nothing works. It does not find the namespace. I'll edit my post to include more details

@KenWhite Is it okay now? I tried to summarize the issue. Do you think it could be more specific within the allotted character limit?

Seems like you are missing the reference in the MauiAPP -> Dependencies -> Add TestApp.Shared project
EDIT: As pointed out in comments, the problem is actually related to a confusing VS combobox where it 'Shows your code as Android'. You can check the github issue about that here.

I already have the reference. If I had not, it wouldn't have worked when I use it in /Platforms/Android/MainActivity.cs. I'll edit my original post to include more details.

For me, it could be a bug in VS related to the folder/namespace, since 'Shared' does not exist in the namespace 'TestApp'. Its trying to validate just TestApp.Shared. I had some problems with renaming/adding folders in the past, it actually didn't change the names in underlying design time files. I suggest you try the good and old: derreference the lib project, copy the content in the problematic file, delete it and it's folder, create a new folder and paste it back, then build it, reference it back and try again.

That could have been that, indeed. I've deleted the TestApp.Shared.Dtos project, closed VS, deleted the physical files, reopened the solution, created a new Class Library project names "TestApp.Shared2.Dtos2" (to make sure it was different). I set the dependencies and changed the usings. Unfortunately, I get exactly the same behavior and the same error (with the new namespaces), Thanks for the idea though.

See this link. It's related to a option where VS 'Shows your code as Android', it could explain the behavior. You should switch it to Windows.

Wow... indeed, I switched it to Windows and it works. Thanks a lot. I find it a bit unintuitive though... Microsoft should make that subject more accessible and the error message more verbose. Thanks again.
